# Binding not working?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, bind

Most of my bindings are working fine but one just displays: Test.Models.PersonModel

The property ("Name") where I like to bind to is in this class.

Here the part where I bind:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <StackPanel Margin="24, 4, 4, 4"
                Orientation="Horizontal">   
       <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"
                  FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"
                  Text="{Binding Name}" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Persons is a OberservableCollection of the type PersonModel. Here the code of the PersonModel:

```
public class PersonModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = null;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
    private BitmapImage _profilpicture = null;

    public BitmapImage ProfilPicture
    {
        get { return _profilpicture; }
        set { _profilpicture = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ProfilPicture"); }
    }

    #region PropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Can you post relevant code for `PersonModel` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ItemTemplate` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx)):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Margin="24, 4, 4, 4"  
                         Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"
                            Text="{Binding Name}" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```